# Dialogflow update user in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dialogflow-es

How would I update a specific user's data in firestore using Dialogflow. There doesn't seem to be any way of getting the user's uid using a fulfillment. I've seen several tutorials about supposedly updating a user with Dialogflow but none actually do--they just write data to a collection not specific to any user. This is an internal company chatbot with all users having firebase authentication.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to achieve and expect to happen using the chatbot ? So I can better understand your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The fulfillment sends a JSON payload to your webhook endpoint. This contains the session ID:

```
    sessionInfo: {
        session: 'projects/your-project/locations/location/agents/agent-id/sessions/**session-id**'
    }
```

You can extract the session ID and use that as a unique identifier for your user's session.

An example of doing this via JavaScript:

```
const id = request.body.sessionInfo.session.split("/").reverse()[0];
```

You can read more about session ID's here: [Session ID documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/session).
These can be generated automatically or provided by you.

In your scenario, you could provide your user ID as the session ID and then when your fulfillment is called it will pass that to your webhook.

[Dialogflow messenger integration instructions](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/dialogflow-messenger#html-customize)